# ng-mouseleave triggers on mouseenter

Tags: angularjs, mouseevent

I attached the ng-mouseleave event to my html tag. Unfortunately it triggers twice. Once when the user leaves the website which is fine and once when he enters the website, which is not wanted. I have a console.log on the event.

The plunkr:
http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/rjfyCw/

index.html

```
    <html ng-app="myApp" id="myApp" ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl" ng-mouseleave="mainCtrl.log('xy')">
```

Controller.js

```
myAppControllers.controller('MainController', [ function () {
    this.log = function(log) {
      console.log(log);
    };

  }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because event is triggered on child elements as well, you need to stop this manually:

```
ng-mouseleave="mainCtrl.log($event, 'xy')"
```

and

```
this.log = function($event, log) {
      $event.stopPropagation()
      console.log(log);
    };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/sSpqiIqMz3rVYzrPQ0iC?p=preview